# Azure DevOps vs Microsoft AppCenter

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

My project has two web apps (.NET) and 2 mobile apps (mobile apps built in Xamarin and deployed in iOS and Android).

Team is unclear on trade-offs between using Azure DevOps and MS AppCenter.

From this SO item 
[What's the principal difference between MS AppCenter and Azure DevOps (former VSTS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669467/whats-the-principal-difference-between-ms-appcenter-and-azure-devops-former-vs)

it seems that "...App Center is for mobile app deployment & monitoring whereas DevOps is for any-platform development & deployment."

But what are the trade offs between the two? I think we would like to do all builds in Azure DevOps and then feed these builds into App Center for deployment and monitoring, but is it possible to do this?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use Azure DevOps and deploy from there to App Center. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/vsts-deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App center is great if you want to quickly build and distribute mobile apps, it have build in tempate to deploy app to App Store , Google Play Store, Intune as well as analytics. However, the CI/CD is not very customisable.

Azure Devops is great for CI/CD customisable, you can configure the build, trigger build on pull request and etc... Also you can configure stages in CD. Also good for keeping your project, code and ci/cd in one place. However the deployment for mobile apps is not great, as there are no built in template at the moment, you can write your own yaml or get template from the market though.

Integration from Azure Devops and VS App Center give the best experience in my opinion.

Comment: Actually, Azure DevOps also have the mobile apps deployment templates (in case if you go with classic "UI" approach of pipelines setup), but in general the whole bunch of functionality might be embarrassing in the beginning, so AppCenter allows to do the standard deploys just easier and simpler.